В браузере иконка сайта (Favicon) должна информировать о изменении файла json
При изменении параметра "options"/"preset" в файле geojson необходимо запускать скрипт "мигания Favicon", с условием, если цвет метки "islands#redCircleIcon", то запускать скрипт мигания, если таких меток в файле json нет, то выключить. Сейчас реализовано на кнопке включить/выключить. Подскажите как это сделать, возможно надо парсить файл json.
В ссылке рабочий вариант (вверху сайта кнопки, открыть на полный экран чтобы увидеть в действии)
[рабочий вариант сайта][1]
 `https://plnkr.co/edit/sKukmzQ7lItW2WGy`  [1]: 


Вы видели где-то данную реализацию, или это с области "гениальных идей" ? Мне кажеться, что чисто физически данные про фаиконку отдаються раньше чем все другое, в том числе и ваши данные... поэтому вам надо плясать от конца. Сначало как-то узнавать про изменения а уже потом делать подмену фавиконки... Хотя это как-по мне тупость. Поскольку вы эту проверку каждому клиенту совать будите. Не оптимально.

По моему все элементарно делается, если бы я был программистом. Например раз в 5 минут парсится файл json на предмет наличия выражения 'red' , если условие выполняется, то програмно "нажать" кнопку '#start' - если нет 'red' - нажать кнопку '#stop'.

Где этот json лежит? Кто его меняет и как? Если все происходит на серверной части, то лучше использовать SSE - при изменении данных, проверить значение и если оно изменилось разослать всем активным уведомление, а клиент это получит и ключит/выключит моргание.
